# How to Create an XML Serializer for More than One Type?

Tags: c#

I am using the XmlSerializer like this,

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(myType));
```

Now I have 5 different "myType". How do I pass the specific type dynamically so I don't have to repeat the same code 5 times?

Comment: What code do you find yourself repeating five times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());`.

Comment: Good idea. I like it better than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

typeof(myType) will not compile unless myType is a type.

If you have an instance of the type, you can do instance.GetType();

There is not other option im afraid. You have to specify some type compile time anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to have a generic method. Consider this example:

```
static T DeserializeObject<T>(XmlReader reader)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    T t = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    return t;
}
```

Using it:

```
static void Main()
{
    string xml = "<Foo><Blah>Hello World</Blah></Foo>";

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(xml)))
    {
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
        Foo foo = DeserializeObject<Foo>(reader);

        Console.WriteLine(foo.Blah);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Anthony: -1 for no `using` blocks.

Answer (score -1):

Just create a little function and have the parameter be of type 'Type'.

```
    private void SerializeType(Type theType)
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(theType);
    }
```

Comment: Isn't this just wrapping the initialization of `XmlSerializer` in another function? And how does it help with initializing different types?